# Error - There is no extension able to load the configuration for "app.mail_manager"

Tags: php, symfony-2.8

I'm using symfony 2.8. I'm creating new service for sending email. Here is my service class,

```
<?php 
namespace AppBundle\Service;

class MailManager
{   


    public function sendEmail($template, $sender, $recepient, $recepientEmail, $recepientSubject, $recepientMessage, $recepientCreated)
    {
         try{
            $message = (new \Swift_Message('Contact Us Notitfication'))
            ->setFrom($sender)
            ->setTo($recepientEmail)
            ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                // app/Resources/views/Emails/registration.html.twig
                 $template,
                 array('name' => $recepient, 'email' => $recepientEmail, 'subject' => $recepientSubject, 'message' => $recepientMessage, 'created_at'=> $recepientCreated )
            ),
            'text/html'
            );

            $response = $this->get('mailer')->send($message);


        }   catch(Exception $e){
             $request->getSession()
                     ->getFlashBag()
                     ->add('error', $e->getMessage());

            return $this->redirectToRoute('contact'); 
        }

        return $response;
    }

}
```

And in my services.yml file I included this,

```
app.mail_manager:
        class:     AppBundle\Service\MailManager
        arguments: []
```

Now I got this error

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "app.mail_manager" (in C:\xampp\htdocs\mydoctor\app/config\servi
>         ces.yml). Looked for namespace "app.mail_manager", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doct
>         rine", "sensio_framework_extra", "app", "mobile_detect", "debug", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution"

How to resolve this error. Please help